# Prettify syntax highlighter doesn't run in tag wiki pages (did run in edit page however)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, syntax-highlighting

The prettify syntax highlighter doesn't run in tag wiki pages (does run in edit preview page however). For example [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

---

**Update:** I just encountered exactly the same problem again. For JSP and Servlets it works fine *(although the JSP one should apply XML/HTML syntax highlighting rather than Java syntax highlighting, but that aside)*, but for [Servlet Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) it doesn't work at all, while it does work in edit page. Does syntax highlighting need to be configured on a per-tag basis or so?

---

**Update 2:** the highlighter also doesn't run in [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) info page where I'd expect XML-like syntax highlighting. After investigating the CSS it turns out that SO is using a tag-specific classname (which matches the most popular tag) to trigger language-specific syntax highlighting. I'd suggest to add a default classname which triggers automatic highlighting for the case that there's no match in tags.

That said, I'm also not very happy to see that [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) (and JSF) posts uses Java-targeted syntax highlighting. It should be using XML-targeted syntax highlighting (or better, automatic, since it's often a mix of Java code and XML-style code in those posts). However, most JSP questions are posted along with a `[java]` tag as well which causes the wrong syntax highlighter to be triggered. About half a year ago everything in JSP/JSF/JSTL tags was highlighted perfectly.

Or does that deserve another question?

Comment: Yerp, totally fixing this ASAP, you wrote some awesome wikis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sorted now, sorry about about it.

Comment: Unaccepted because the same problem occurred on other tag. Can you take a look once again?

Comment: @BalusC ... will have a look

Comment: Thanks... JSF 2.0 has by the way also no default highlighting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823216/jsf-2-0-form-using-get In preview page it looks perfect. *Sob*.

Comment: @BalusC ... hmm I manually set it to XML ... but not really sure why I had to

Comment: Looks better. But why not just default? JSP/JSTL/JSF questions may contain a mix of Java code and XML style code.

Comment: Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822107/jsf-2-0-query-string-propagation), XML is fine, but Java is not highlighted. If you're unsure, who was then responsible for the change in syntax highlighting? You might delegate the job to him/her.

Comment: @BaluC see here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting - if you'd like to suggest new tags and language hints do so there.

Comment: @Geoff: ah, I've completely missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Btw: I've [reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/76980#76980) it there, but no changes has taken place since then. What should happen? What do Jeff expect more? 10 votes or something?